# Evaluating whether a version number is one WHOLE version less than another

Tags: php, operators

I am writing a script to find every Wordpress install on a server and create a report detailing the outdated versions. This works fine. I'd simply like to change the formatting to "danger" if the version number is more than a whole number behind.

Eg. Currently Wordpress is at version 4.7.3, so I would "warn" on 4.5.0 (which is already working) - but what is the login to identify anything *less than 4.0.0*.

Thanks very much.

Here's the start of the script:

```
$url='https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/';

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = utf8_encode($contents);
$versions = json_decode($contents);

$upgrade        = $versions->offers[0];
$WPversion      = $upgrade->version;
$WPmajorVersion = $WPversion[0]; //This will work to get the first digit right?
```

Then (once I am looping installs) I am simply after the:

```
if($version *[THIS]* $WPMajorVersion){
  //Big warning
} else {
  //Small warning
}
```

Comment: What does the `utf8_encode()` do in there? The API certainly does deliver UTF8 encoded data already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is the slightly more correct version:

```
<?php
$url='https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/';

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$versions = json_decode($contents);

$wpUpgradeVersionString = $versions->offers[0]->version;
$wpUpgradeVersion = array_map('intval', explode('.', $wpUpgradeVersionString));

var_dump($wpUpgradeVersion[0]);
```

It delivers the integer value `4`as output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, very interesting. The crucial bit is later in the script though, I may not have explained well enough. Once I HAVE the version (say "4") I need to compare that against the versions on the box and output an extra warning if THOSE versions (say 3.6.1) are less than 4. Although even as I write it I am clearing my crazy mental block on that issue haha. I think I just need to again get the first digit! Doh!

Comment: @mayersdesign Correct, when comparing version numbers `4.1.2` is indeed a whole version higher than `3.8.8`. Only the major version number counts for that. Glad I could be of help!